# Is 'what is this font/what is the font in x' on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Sometimes I can see questions about what is the font at particular places, eg:

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36469749/what-is-ios-9-3-system-font-name)

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23776754)

I know sometimes font name is programming related because it may need to set the font programmatically, especially in mobile applications. But I also found some questions that looks not like programming related:

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683361)

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22624432)

So my question is, when is on topic when asking about 'what is the font in x/what is this font'? Or are they always off topic?

Comment: Essentially, (as far as I can make out), the only close reason with any relevance is the "recommend or find a resource", so it comes down to are you asking someone what is the name of a resource, or if you're asking them where you can get it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What is the font in x/what is this font?

Font identification questions are on-topic on http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com:

> We do accept questions about the identification of fonts, if certain conditions are met (see our [requirements for font-identification questions](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/what-are-the-requirements-for-font-identification-questions)).

Source [What topics can I ask about here?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: While that is true, the question still appears to me about whether or not they are on topic on [so]